# Incompatibility between xr-hyper and redefinition of \section

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, xr

This is `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontohead]{scrbook}
\usepackage{subfiles, xparse, xr-hyper, hyperref}
\externaldocument{main} % so that cross-references work in subfiles

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{o m}{
% I want the header to appear only when a short version of the section title is supplied
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\oldsection[head={}]{#2}}{\oldsection[#1]{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\subfile{bar.tex}
\ref{sec:bar}

\end{document}
```

This is `bar.tex`:

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{bar}
\label{sec:bar}
\end{document}
```

This is the error I get when compiling `main.tex`:

> ```
> <argument> \Sectionformat 
>                           {bar}{\numexpr \csname sectionnumdepth\endcsname \...
> l.5 
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed.
> ```

I guess there is something wrong with my redefinition of `\section`. Please help me fix it!

Comment: Did you investigate whether xr-hyperref is actually related to this issue? Aka does it happen without xr.

Comment: @daleif Yes; if you comment out the `\externaldocument`, there is no error.

Comment: Then you might need to delay the redefinition using `\AtBeginDocument{...} `

Comment: @daleif Tried that, no luck.

Comment: Including the let?

Comment: @daleif yes, both with the let and without

Comment: I am known to be no fan of the KOMA classes but you should use `\RedeclareSectioningCommand`, not something like `\RenewDocumentCommand` in conjunction with KOMA stuff

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That does not allow for adding custom code, only changing specific attributes AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not related to your redefinition or to subfiles. When using the `[headings=optiontohead]` option the expansion of labels is changed, and so the `\Sectionformat` command is written to the aux-file. As hyperref (nameref) defines `\Sectionformat` only at begin document, you get an error when the `\externaldocument` loads the aux-file. You can try to add a default definition:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontohead]{scrbook}
\providecommand\Sectionformat[2]{#1} %<----- new
\usepackage{xr-hyper,hyperref}

\externaldocument{test-utf8} % 

\begin{document}

\section[]{abc} \label{sec:bar}
\ref{sec:bar}

\end{document}
```